# How do I solve CS1579?

Tags: c#, json

I deserialized this JSON Data

```
StreamReader file = new StreamReader("UserInfo.json");
var json = file.ReadToEnd();
User[] user = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<User[]>(json);
```

this is the JSON file, if needed

```
[
    {
        "userId": 3017221209,
        "displayName": "some person"
    }, 
    {
        "userId": 1690049096,
        "displayName": "another person"
    }
]
```

here's my User class

```
public class User
{
    public long userId { get; set; }
    public string displayName { get; set; }
}
```

and I have this foreach loop

```
foreach (var UserIds in user[].userId) 
{ 
    // stuff
}
```

which gave me

> foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'long' because 'long' does not contain a public instance or extension definition for 'GetEnumerator'

**how do I fix this? I watched a few tutorials on this but was still confused**

Comment: Do you really want to iterate over userIds? Or do you want to iterate over users?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax you're trying to use just won't work - `user[].userId` isn't a valid expression, and if it *did* resolve to a `userId` value, that would just be a single `long`, which you can't iterate over.

Assuming you're trying to iterate over all the user IDs, there are two options:

- Use a `foreach` loop to iterate over users, and then take the user ID of each user:

  ```cs
  string json = File.ReadAllText("UserInfo.json");
  User[] users = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<User[]>(json);
  foreach (var user in users)
  {
      long userId = user.userId;
      // Use userId
  }
  ```
- Use LINQ to project to a sequence of user IDs, and iterate over that:

  ```cs
  string json = File.ReadAllText("UserInfo.json");
  User[] users = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<User[]>(json);
  foreach (var userId in users.Select(user => user.userId))
  {
      // Use userId
  }
  ```

Note that I've changed the variable name for the array from `user` to `users`, to indicate that it represents a collection of users instead of a single one. It's worth taking care over variable names to ensure they're as clear as possible.

I'd also strongly advise you to follow .NET naming conventions, where your property names would be `UserId` and `DisplayName`.